# Embed font in ActionScript class in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, fonts, embed

When creating an mxml component it is easy to embed the desired font in this way:

```
@font-face {
    src: local("Arial");
    fontFamily: ArialEmbedded;
}
```

In my code I need to embed the font for a component that is the part of the class implemented in *.as file. How can I do this?

Regards, Rafal

Answer (score 3):

I covered this a few weeks ago on my site. There's too much info to copy/paste here, so you can get it at: http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass

There's code & source files as well. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: OK. But how to apply the TextFormat object to VBox that contains Text objects?

Comment: can you not just set the font property directly on the Text object and flex will pick it up? (use a slight rotation on the text object to see if it's embedded). You could also try the styles on the Text object: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Text.html#commonStyleSummary

Comment: also, there's the help file for embedding fonts in flex 4: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html#WS02f7d8d4857b1677-11e364d1266679ac18-8000 - it's full of useful info

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple sample how you can embed font in custom ActionScript component:

```
package
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import mx.core.IUITextField;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.core.UITextField;

[Style(name="fontFamily", type="String", inherit="yes")]
public class ComponentWithFontEmbedding extends UIComponent
{
    private var label:IUITextField;

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();

        if (!label)
        {
            label = IUITextField(createInFontContext(UITextField));
            label.styleName = this;
            addChild(DisplayObject(label));
            label.text = "Hello";
        }
    }

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        measuredWidth = measuredMinWidth = 100;
        measuredHeight = measuredMinHeight = 50;
    }
}
}
```

I omitted real measurement for simplicity. So the code is pretty simple and uses very lightweight UITextField. But you can use Label the similar way using styling.

The sample usage is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
    <mx:Style>
        @font-face {
            src: local("Arial");
            fontFamily: ArialEmbedded;
        }
    </mx:Style>
    <local:ComponentWithFontEmbedding fontFamily="ArialEmbedded" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />
</mx:Application>
```

Hope this helps.